# Inserting values from one table to another MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to insert the data from one of my tables to another
This is the filled table that I have:

```
 Act (
 id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 birth_date DATETIME,
 death_date DATETIME,
 place VARCHAR(20)  
 );
```

In this table some of the values are NULL - for example if it's a birth act then death_date is NULL.

And this is the table I want to transfer data into:

```
 Population_Growth (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 number_of_births INT,
 number_of_deaths INT,
 place VARCHAR(20),
 time DATE
 );
```

In the end I would like this table to show number of deaths and number of births in the same place and the same date. As for numbers of births and deaths I would do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Population_Growth (number_of_births, number_of_deaths) VALUES 
((COUNT (birth_date) FROM Act WHERE birth_date IS NOT NULL)), 
((COUNT (death_date) FROM Act WHERE death_date IS NOT NULL));
```

However I don't know how to relate it with the corresponding time and date.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the specified result would be a query like this:

```
SELECT c.place
     , c.time
     , SUM(c.count_births) AS number_of_births
     , SUM(c.count_deaths) AS number_of_deaths
  FROM (
         SELECT b.place
              , DATE(b.birth_date) AS `time`
              , SUM(1) AS count_births
              , SUM(0) AS count_deaths
           FROM Act b
          WHERE b.birth_date IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY b.place, DATE(b.birth_date)
          UNION ALL
         SELECT d.place
              , DATE(d.death_date) AS `time`
              , SUM(0) AS count_births
              , SUM(1) AS count_deaths
           FROM Act d
          WHERE d.death_date IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY d.place, DATE(d.death_date)
       ) c
  GROUP BY c.place, c.time
```

To turn that into an insert, precede the SELECT with:

```
INSERT INTO Population_Growth (place, `time`, number_of_births, number_of_deaths)
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The query above casts the DATETIME columns to a DATE datatype (by truncating the time portion.)

To get the summary by year and month, but still as a form valid for assignment to a `DATE` column, one option is to replace all of the expressions:

```
DATE(b.birth_date)
DATE(d.death_date)
```

(in the query above) with these expressions:

```
DATE_FORMAT(b.birth_date,'%Y-%m-01')
DATE_FORMAT(d.death_date,'%Y-%m-01')
```

The new expressions will extract the year and month from the DATETIME column, and set the day component to the 1st of the month.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the count of non-NULL values from two date columns.  Here is one approach to getting the summary:

```
select place, d,
       (select count(*) from act where act.birth_date = pd.d and act.place = pd.place) as births,
       (select count(*) from act where act.death_date = pd.d and act.place = pd.place) as deaths
from (select place, birth_date as d from act union
      select place, death_date from act
     ) pd;
```

You can then put this into `population_growth` by doing:

```
INSERT INTO Population_Growth(place, time, number_of_births, number_of_deaths) 
    select place, d,
           (select count(*) from act where act.birth_date = pd.d and act.place = pd.place) as births,
           (select count(*) from act where act.death_date = pd.d and act.place = pd.place) as deaths
    from (select place, birth_date as d from act union
          select place, death_date from act
         ) pd;
```

Comment: I believe OP also wants the `DATETIME` columns in `Act` cast to `DATE` type. (I concur with the need of a UNION (or UNION ALL) set operation to combine the `birth_date` and `death_date` into a single list of DATE values.)

Comment: This seems to work ok, but the thing is I would like it to number of deaths and births in the same date meaning year and month (sorry for lack of information). I guess column name "time" is also confusing.

Comment: @BesSa . . . `time` is not confusing at all because you have it typed as a `date`.  I would suggest that you edit your question with actual data and desired results or possibly ask a new question so you don't invalidate the current answers.